# Point with connected geodesic circles on closed convex surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a closed convex surface (smooth if necessary) and denote by $d$ the intrinsic distance on $S$. Can we always find a point $p$ such that $S_p(t):=\{q\in S\mid d(p,q)=t\}$ stays connected for all $t\geq 0$?

Comment: How about a sphere?

Comment: For a round sphere, this is true for any point. I'm wondering if there is a surface without such a point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 2-dimensional flat equilateral triangle $T_i$. If we glue
along boundary $\partial T_1= \partial T_2$, then we have a convex
surface $\Sigma$. Then note that **any point does not hold the
property**

Notation and setting : If $v_i$ are three vertices in $\Sigma$, then fix an
interior point $x\in T_1$. Assume that $v_1$ is the closest vertex
to a point $x$. And we define $y_i\in [v_1v_i] $ s.t. $$
|v_1y_2|=|v_1y_3|=\varepsilon$$ and $v_1y_2xy_3$ is in circle of
radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\varepsilon$ and center $o$

Now we will show that **some geodesic sphere of $x$ is not connected** :

(1) If $f(\theta )=|xy_2|+|xy_3|+|y_2y_3|$ where
$\theta=\angle(\overrightarrow{ oy_2},\overrightarrow{ox} )$ then
$f$ has a maximum at $ \theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$. And
$$f(\frac{\pi}{3} ) =r,\ r=\frac{2+\sqrt{3} }{\sqrt{3} }
\varepsilon$$

Here $r<r_0$ where $r_0= \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}} \varepsilon = 2|v_1x| $

(2) Assume that a point $x_2\in T_2$ satisfies that there are at
least two shortest paths from $x$ to $x_2$. Further note that there is a point $x_2$ s.t. $|xx_2|$ has the minimum. Hence $|xx_2|\leq r$. Hence for some $R\leq
\frac{r+r_0}{2}$, the geodesic sphere $S_R(x)$ is not connected, since
the geodesic ball $B_R(x)$ does not contains a vertex $v_1$

Comment: Why do you say so? It appears  that each point on this surface has  all connected spheres.

Comment: I add more explanation.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the proof but what if the center is one of the vertices?

Comment: $d(y_1,v_2) <d(v_1,v_2)$ where $y_1\in [v_1v_3]$ is close to $v_1$. So a closed ball $B(v_2,d(y_1,v_2))$ does not contain $v_1,\ v_3$ but contains two minimizing geodesics from $v_2$ to $y_1$.

Comment: @HL Lee: I do not see why this ball has disconnected boundary, it looks connected to me.

Comment: Frankly, I do not understand your point, that leads to the connected boundary of $t$-ball for all $t>0$. Can you explain the connectedness ?

Comment: It is quite simple. Take one vertex $v=v_1$ of the square $Q$. Draw the $r$-ball $B(v,R)$ in $Q$. Its topological frontier in $Q$ is a single Euclidean arc $a$. When you double $Q$, the frontier of $B(v,R)$ in $Q$ is the double of $a$, i.e. a topological circle, which is of course connected.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, why do we consider a square $Q$ ?

Comment: You can take a triangle instead, it does not matter. The key observation that a Euclidean circle centered at a vertex (the one with acute angle) will intersect this triangle in a connected subset.

Comment: I do not understand why Euclidean circle at a vertex intersects the triangle in connected subset.

Comment: This is not hard, but you may have to think about it for more than 3 minutes. In any case, this is your answer and I am not planning to write detailed proofs in comments to it.

Comment: In your previous comment, in double $Q$ you insist that frontier of
$B(v,R)$ where $v$ is a vertex is a circle when $R$ is small. This
argument holds for double $T$ where $T$ is an equilateral triangle.
This is your opinion ? Do I understand correctly ?

Comment: I now understand your example, it is correct.  (+1) Just add a reference to Alexandrov's theorem that this surface embeds isometrically in $R^3$ as a convex surface.